# Access Selenium IDE output in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm having this requirement in which i need to access an element on my page and want to get all the properties of the element. I have already written a webdriver script to get the id,name,css,linktext but i'm not getting the idea how to get the xpath and css selector for that element.

One thing which i'm having in my mind is select the element using Selenium Ide and in the Select tab it will get all the attribute value which is very useful for me, but how to get this result in my selenium webdriver.

I dont know whether this is possible or not but if someone can give me some reference that will be very useful.

Hope for some positive answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate absolute xpath. Please take a look at this: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5520

Answer (score 0):

Css and xpath selectors are based on the element attributes and/or tags.

You can write a method to generate some selectors but this does not guarantee that your selector would be efficient and it can break even when a slight change in the page is done.

Even if you are using a method like @arun-prakash suggested for xpath is the same thing. I don't see the reason behind this.

You will have to use a selector to identify the element so why get the selector again? You should ask the reason and how these selectors would be used.

Comment: Is it possible to get the values from SELECT column in Selenium IDE into WebDriver script? That can also help me.